# How to avoid heading tag extend on all the line?

Tags: html, css

I have this standard situation:

```
<h1>Title</h1>
<h2>Subtitle</h2>
<p>Text</p>
```

Now, I styled h1 and h2 with a bottom-border that gives una underlining effect

```
border-bottom: 1px dashed #999999;
```

This looks nice, however, since h1 and h2 extend on all the width, the underline effect goes past the text. I tried to solve with display: inline-block; but that works only on some pages, while on others (where title or subtitle are short) the two heading lines go next to each other

I know I could solve this by adding a span inside the heading, but I´d like to know if there is any nifty css solution that would avoid inserting an extra element in the html (and rewriting many pages).

Thank you in advance.

Kind regards!

Comment: Well, since these are block-type elements, this is default behaviour. If you don't want to use extra elements, nor pseudo elements, it will not be possible to achieve it from where I see it. Maybe with a very hacky trick, but that would be overkill in my opinion...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nifty CSS yes, though as you note in your comment below, if you wish to support IE7, there is no CSS solution.

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gdy24/)

You could do, e.g.

```
h1{ display:inline; }
h1:after { content:"\A"; white-space:pre; }
```

This will add a newline after the element.

Comment: While I no longer support IE7- in my projects, I do still try to avoid things that will critically break in it - which this will, due to lack of support for `:after`.

Comment: Afraid, you can't do this without using further elements if you wish to support IE7

Comment: Or by adding a script: `<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<script src="http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version/2.1(beta4)/IE8.js"></script>
<![endif]-->`

Comment: [Demo of old IE](http://jsfiddle.net/Gdy24/1/) Also, your solution eliminates the margin of the heading.

Answer (score 1):

While the effect can be produced with either `float:left` or `display:inline-block`, both introduce more problems.

It would be significantly easier to change your HTML to this:

```
<h1><span>Title</span></h1>
```

Then your CSS:

```css
h1>span {border-bottom: 1px dashed #999}
```

This will cause the border to only appear for the width of the text.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use <u> tag explained below

<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <p>This is a <u>parragraph mb mbmnbkjkjnkj </u>.</p>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Just write this in ur css

```
u {    
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/arjun_chaudhary/qBRV5/

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol use css as mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by sizing the content and avoiding the wrap. Thus keeping it IE7 friendly

```
.wrapper h1{
    margin-left:10px;
    border-bottom:1px solid black;
    width:300px;
    text-align:center;
    white-space:nowrap;
 }
```

See ***[DEMO HERE](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lhmIn/)***